# How can I create image from html using PHP?

Tags: php

something like painty but with advanced options having div, font, fontsize, style... etc....

I would like to have a coupon design in html and output it  as an image.. preferably JPG..

but painty is not supporting those.

you can find here.. http://www.rabuser.info/painty.php  the painty code i am using right now.

Thanks and waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

There's [khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=faq), which renders the whole page and takes a screenshot; however, it's a standalone executable (and it needs an X server or xvfb), so you need to be able to run it on your server (so probably not on a shared hosting). This may be a bit of an overkill, but it gives you complete control over the final appearance.

You could also use some of the [HTML to PDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) convertors and then use ImageMagick to convert the PDF to JPEG.

Comment: Thanks Piskvor... for the reply... but i need to select particular part of an html and make a nice image...

Comment: @saikat gupta: And how do my suggestions differ from that? Please be specific, "that's not exactly the way I need" is not very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Creating this with pure php is bad idea, this will be slow as hell. 
As far as I know in production this is achieved with external screenshot app and standard browser run by `exec()` or similar function.

Comment: Adam.. Thanks for the reply...  but i think screenshot application will make my image quality very bad.. is in't it?

Comment: I think google, firefox search preview addon, browsershots.org and many other companies use this method and quality is good. Everything depends on the software and size/quality ratio